# Decreasing the height bootstrap navbar size without using less?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to decrease the height of the Bootstrap 3.1.1's navbar without using the less version of it. I have tried several ways of doing this by reading around on different sites, and none of them are decreasing the CSS's `.navbar` height.

I have managed to fix the padding on the `.navbar-nav > li > a`.

My HTML:

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">QuadCMS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/support/">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

My CSS which overrides the Bootstrap to try to fix the navbar.

```
.navbar {
   height: 25px !important;
   }

.navbar-nav > li > a { 
   padding-top: 5px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
   }
```

My main issue is with the actual height of the navbar, not the padding now. The padding of the navigation links are fixed and working at the small size. I have also tried changing the `.navbar` to `.navbar-nav`, and `.navbar-fixed-top` respectfully and nothing has worked yet.

Do I need to call a different CSS Class then the ones I have tried, or do I need to call two of the ones I have already tried to get the effect needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the default `.navbar` styling:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You need to overwrite the `min-height` property. You can use the value `inherit`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NsMY/)

```
.navbar {
    height: 30px;
    min-height: inherit;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
}
```